# Save a file with the extension .f90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I typed the source code in WordPad and saved it as *addition.f90* but, unfortunately, the only options Windows provides are text files, rtf's, and so forth.

I am using the G95 compiler for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the WordPad Save dialog, type the filename in double quotes, e.g. `"addition.f90"`.  This will override the default extension.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a decent text editor instead. Have a look at [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm), [VIM](http://www.vim.org), [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or similar.

To rename a file in Windows you either use the command prompt:

```
rename file.f90.rtf file.f90
```

Or you can use the Windows explorer. Make sure you set it up to display file extensions. Under Tools | Folder Options, unselect 'Hide extensions for known file types'. To rename a file, either select it and press F2, or right-click and select Rename.

Comment: The command prompt method works (+1), but it is impossible in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Perhaps the folder options dialog is different under Vista. I suggest you google it: http://www.google.com/search?q=vista+folder+options

Comment: @codeape, thanks, I am now using notepad++. You were right: changing the file extension in Windows Explorer does work. What I did wrong was clicking No on the pop-up warning, when it asked me if I was sure that I wanted to change the extension, since the file could become unusable in such a case.